# Print Arabic character through thermal printer using android application

Tags: android, kotlin, printing, usb

i hvae used this amazing library [ESCPOS ThermalPrinter Android](https://github.com/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android) to print recipt through thermal printer and it works fine but when it comes to add arabic words it never shows up
here is my code
`

```
private val usbReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION == intent.action) {
            synchronized(this) {

                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    usbDevice?.apply {
                            printer.printFormattedText(
                                "[C]<img>" + PrinterTextParserImg.bitmapToHexadecimalString(printer, applicationContext.resources.getDrawableForDensity(R.drawable.logo, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM)) +"</img>\n" +
                                        "[L]\n" +
                                        "[C]ريفلو\n" +
                                        "[C]جده - حي العزيزية\n" +
                                        "[C]<u>فاتورة ضريبية مبسطة</u>\n" +
                                        "[C]<u>Simplified Tax Invoice</u>\n" +
                                        "[L]<b>VAT Reg No.<b>[R]310473657600003[R]<b>رقم الضريبي<b>\n" +
                                        "[L]<b>Invoice No.<b>[R]AT0186[R]<b>رقم الفاتورة<b>\n" +
                                        "[L]<b>Date<b>[R]13-10-2022 11:05 AM [R]<b>تاريخ<b>\n" +
                                        "[L]\n" +

                                        "[C]--------------------------------\n" +

                                        "[L]\n" +
                                        "[L]<b>البيانـــــــــــات</b>[R]<b>كمية</b>[R]<b>سعر الوحده</b>[R]<b>ضريبة</b>[R]<b>الاجمالى</b>\n" +
                                        "[L]\n" +

                                        "[C]--------------------------------\n" +

                                        "[L]كوب كبير[R]1[R]21[R]2.74[R]21.00"+
                                        "[L]Large Cup"+
                                        "[L]\n" +
                                        "[L]كوب عادي[R]1[R]11[R]1.43[R]11.00"+
                                        "[L]Regular Cup"+
                                        "[L]\n" +
                                        "[L]كابتشينو[R]1[R]91[R]1.17[R]9.00"+
                                        "[L]Cappuccino"+
                                        "[L]\n" +
                                        "[L]حليب شوكلاته[R]1[R]12[R]1.57[R]12.00"+
                                        "[L]Milk Choc"+
                                        "[L]\n" +
                                        "[L]كوب عادي[R]1[R]11[R]1.43[R]11.00"+
                                        "[L]Regular Cup"+
                                        "[L]\n" +
                                        "[L]بسكويت اطفال[R]1[R]9[R]1.17[R]9.00"+
                                        "[L]Kids Cone"+
                                        "[L]\n" +
                                        "[L]كوب عادي فاخر[R]1[R]15[R]1.96[R]15.00"+
                                        "[L]Regular Cup Premium"+
                                        "[L]\n" +
                                        "[L]بسكويت فاخر[R]1[R]15[R]1.96[R]15.00"+
                                        "[L]Premium Cone"+
                                        "[L]\n" +

                                        "[C]--------------------------------\n" +

                                        "[L]\n" +
                                        "[L]قيمة المنتجــات[R][R][R][R]89.57"+
                                        "[L]Products Value ( Excl.VAT)"+
                                        "[L]\n" +
                                        "[L]خصم[R][R][R][R]0.00"+
                                        "[L]Discount(-)"+
                                        "[L]\n" +
                                        "[L]ضريبة القيمة المضافة[R][R][R][R]13.43"+
                                        "[L]VAT (15%)"+
                                        "[L]\n" +
                                        "[L]المجموع الكلي[R][R][R][R]103.00"+
                                        "[L]Grand Total"+
                                        "[L]\n" +
                                        "[L]Total 8 Items\n" +

                                        "[C]--------------------------------\n" +

                                        "[L] المبلغ المدفوع - نقدا[R][R][R][R]3.00"+
                                        "[L]Amount In Cash"+
                                        "[L]\n" +
                                        "[L]لمبلغ المدفوع - البطاقة[R][R][R][R]105.00"+
                                        "[L]Amount By Card "+
                                        "[L]\n" +
                                        "[L]الباقي[R][R][R][R]-5.00"+
                                        "[L]Balance "+
                                        "[L]\n" +
                                        "[C]<qrcode size='20'>http://www.developpeur-web.dantsu.com/</qrcode>\n"+
                                        "[C]****Thank You For Visit Come Again!****")
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "permission denied for device $usbDevice")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fun printUsb(): View.OnClickListener? {

    val usbConnection = UsbPrintersConnections.selectFirstConnected(this)
    val usbManager = this.getSystemService(USB_SERVICE) as UsbManager

    if (usbConnection != null) {
        val permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this,
            0,
            Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION),
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE else 0
        )

        val filter = IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION)
        registerReceiver(usbReceiver, filter)
        usbManager.requestPermission(usbConnection.device, permissionIntent)
    }
    return null
}
```

`

i have tried this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/73275372/13445734 but i don't know how to add it into my code

Comment: Did you buy a printer that supports arabic?  Most thermal printers have very limited character support, generally to latin letters.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [setting the encoding](https://github.com/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/tree/master/escposprinter#charset-encoding) to one that handles Arabic script. I was going to suggest trying `utf-8`, but from the [linked set of IDs](https://www.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=32) that doesn't look like an option. Maybe try the `PC720` one, ID *32*?:

```
val printer = EscPosPrinter(deviceConnection, 203, 48f, 32, EscPosCharsetEncoding("pc720", 32));
```

I'm not sure exactly what name you should use, [there are a few](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_720). I'm also not sure if you'd need to write your text in an editor with that encoding, and then paste it in - I'm just giving you stuff to look into really!

([The default is `Windows-1252`](https://github.com/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/blob/master/escposprinter/src/main/java/com/dantsu/escposprinter/EscPosPrinterCommands.java#L299) which [basically handles Latin script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Codepage_layout) and doesn't have any Arabic characters)